# How to log DNS query response in BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

In Bind, when we enable query logging , it logs the query's details like "query asked", "timestamp" and other stuff. Do we have any options by which i can store the "ANSWER" provided by my recursive node to the client.

i.e.,

For query "dig [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) AAAA" , is there a way by which i can log the ANSWER with respect to the corresponding query, using logging utility of BIND ?

Answer (score 1):

BIND itself does not have an ability to log responses. You'll need to look to other tools such as `dnstap`.

Comment: What about logging queries generated by DNS nodes itself for answering recursive lookups ? 
i.e., if a recursive node receives query for serverfault.com, whose answer is not in cache , then recursive server will have to do query, so anyway of logging these queries ?